# Menu collapse after click

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu

I have this menu, and it is working fine, though, I am building one page website with internal links. When the window resized and mobile menu appears, the links are working, but the menu is not collapsing after click. What do I need to add to my jQuery to achieve this effect?

```
$(function() {
    var pull = $('#pull');
        menu = $('nav ul');

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle(500);
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(this).width();

        if(w > 768 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

    $('li').on('click', function(e) {               
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w < 768 ) {
            menu.slideToggle();
        }
    });

    $('.panel').height($(window).height());

    });
```

My HTML Markup here:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">

    <nav class="cl-effect-4">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#products">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>

    </nav>

</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Add a fiddle with HTML included. That will help us to debug.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, `$(pull)` should be `pull`, right?

[And it works for me, after this modification.](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/rBqMm/)

P.S. Is there some CSS also, because you have called `menu.removeAttr('style');` ? Please put the whole code in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) if there are some additional changes.

Comment: Check the browser console for this site, you have an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lazyload'` and I don't know why but your menu seems to be working. What's the problem there ?

Comment: Thanks, i know. Lazyload library is linked, but not working. I will change that